# System.Drawing not working in c++

Tags: .net, dll, namespaces, c++-cli

I am trying to use namespace `System.Drawing` in `C++`. Despite of the fact that I have referenced required `dll` file which is `System.Drawing.dll` but still I can't use `System.Drawing` namespace.

```
#using <System.Drawing.dll>


using namespace System;
using namespace System.Drawing;

int main()
{




    getch();

}
```

I am getting following error.

`Error  1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'  c:\Users\Labeeb\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\cursor movement\cursor movement\Source.cpp    7   1   cursor movement`

Comment: C++ doesn't use dots to resolve names.

Comment: Are you making a CLI project? Cos `System` isn't C++

Comment: @doctorlove yes its CLI project

Comment: @chris what is alternative? actually I used  dot in C#

Comment: @Labeeb May I suggest that you read my answer :)

Comment: Or look at just about any C++(-CLI) code, really.

Comment: @DanielDaranas sorry read it too late :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.`, use `::` for name scope resolution:

```
using namespace System::Drawing;
```